# How to replace a if-statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the following

```
public class OfferService {
    
    @Autowired
    private OfferRepository offerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    public OfferDto getById(Long id){
        Offer offer = offerRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new OfferException());
        if(offer.getFim().isAfter(LocalDate.now()))
        {
            return modelMapper.map(offer, OfferDto.class);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

So I would like to know how to create a class/interface, so I would replace that if-condition with something else. In fact, I would like to create a class that I could put all my if-statements and conditions.

Comment: Why do you think `if` statements are a problem?  Conditional execution is pretty fundamental to computing.

Comment: I assume what you'd really need here is to move the condition to the query so you don't load the offer, realize it doesn't match and then discard it. If you're using JPA repositories have a look at [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

Comment: Probably create an `OfferValidator`, then inject it and call `if (offerValidator.isValid(offer)) {` and all your validation code is in one class for cleaner code.

Comment: "Probably create an OfferValidator, then inject it and call if (offerValidator.isValid(offer)) { and all your validation code is in one class for cleaner code."
 
> In this case, how would I separate the logic of "if-statement" with the "isAfter" condition in an OfferValidator of its own?